# Python Bokeh - Possibility to use a blend of data coordinate and pixel coordinate for plot

Tags: python, bokeh

Is there a way to use as input for say , the circles glyph the coordinates based on the input data for the x coordinate and input as pixel from top or bottm of chart for the y coordinates?

A bit like the blended transform of matplolib?

Alternatively, it would be easy to convert data coordinate in pixel coordinate, but that is provided that I can find the `y_range` values? I tried `figure.y_range.start` but it doesn't return anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to position glyphs directly using screen space coordinates. It proved to be too difficult to support both that and all the hit-testing machinery that is a core feature of Bokeh. There's two possible workarounds I can imagine.

The first is to to use some sort of `Annotation`. Annotations *can* be positioned in screen coordinates (because they don't participate in hit-testing). There's currently not a "circle" annotation, but perhaps a box or polygon annotation would satisfy your needs. The BoxAnnotation has a section in the users guide and the poly annotation is similar:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#box-annotations

Alternatively, you can create add a second "extra range" that is a proxy for screen (pixel) units. One example of that is here:

```
from bokeh.models import Range1d
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

output_file("foo.html")

p = figure()

# this will only work for fixed layout plots, and you'll have to tune 
# the 'end' property to match your plot dimensions
p.extra_y_ranges = {"foo": Range1d(start=0, end=520)}

p.circle([10, 20, 30], [20, 260, 500], size=10, y_range_name="foo")

show(p)
```

There are also now callbacks for when the plots inner dimensions change. It's possible you could extend that to be more robust/sophisticated in the case of resizable plots. The way to add callbacks for these inner plot dimensions is like this:

```
p.on_change("inner_width", some_callback)
p.on_change("inner_height", some_callback)
```

for python (server) callbacks. Use `js_on_change` for `CustomJS` callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; at the moment i am using something along the lines of: (lets say i am plotting 10 point with x  and y as there coordinates) : `top_range = max(points['y'])` `bottom_range=min(points['y'])` `range=top_range-bottom_range` if I want to place a point at the middle of the chart I would place it at `bottom_range+range*0.5`. However because there is some padding above and below the top and bottom points, this is a bit innacurate. Would there be no way to retrieve the `y_range from` a figure propriety directly?

Comment: Also it is not clear (at least not from the user guide example) how to position an annotation such as a box-annotation in pixel coordinates

Comment: Once you have a starting place, the reference guide is good for questions like that: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/annotations.html#bokeh.models.annotations.BoxAnnotation.left_units

Comment: Also `plot.y_range.start` and `plot.x_range.end`, etc have the default plot range bounds. But if you are using an auto-ranging `DataRange1d` (the default) then these are not set until the plot reaches the browser. (The values are `None` on the "python side") You'll have to use a plain `Range1d` and set start and end to what you need up front. See http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#setting-ranges

Comment: I added information in the answer on how to add callbacks for the inner plot dimensions.